# Insert child template into template of abstract parent in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm trying to insert the template of some child states into a parent state marked as abstract.

In the following example the template of `content.state1` and `content.state2` should be inserted into `<div class="content" ng-view></div>` which is contained in the template of their parent state, `content`.

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('content', {
        abstract: true,
        // Other states should insert their content here
        template: '<div class="content" ng-view></div>'
    })
    .state('content.state1', {
        url: "/state1",
        template: '<h1>Hello from state1!</h1>',
        onEnter: function() { console.log('entering state1'); }
    })
    .state('content.state2', {
        url: "/state2",
        template: '<h1>Hello from state2!</h1>',
        onEnter: function() { console.log('entering state2'); }
    })
});
```

Full example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/EAB3BfYsZc6bTwxm2XuO?p=preview

I can't see why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to use **`ui-view`**, not *ng-view*

```
//template: '<div class="content" ng-view></div>'
template: '<div class="content" ui-view></div>'
```

The same for root, index.html

```
// <div ng-view=""></div>
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

Here is [the updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZWvMnZCGQGg7pi8KKTP0?p=preview)